# How do I make nginx's folder moveable?

Tags: nginx

Currently when I compile nginx (in directory /home/parth/nginx), it embeds the prefix supplied to configure script in the nginx binary. Now when I move that folder around (let's say to /tmp), it breaks with following error message. Is there a way to configure logs file directories?

```
./nginx -p /tmp/ -c /tmp/conf/nginx.conf
```

> nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()
>   "/home/parth/nginx/var/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory) 2012/08/27 02:22:26 [emerg] 23782#0: unknown log format
>   "main" in /tmp/conf/nginx.conf:25

== nginx.conf file ==

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
             root   html;
             index  index.html index.htm;
         }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
         error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
         location = /50x.html {
              root   html;
         }
```

... rest of the file has commented out configuration and closing brackets.            root   html;

Comment: `cat /tmp/conf/nginx.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [emerg] 23782#0: unknown log format "main" in /tmp/conf/nginx.conf:25

```
#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

Uncomment the `log_format` line and try again.

Comment: ok that worked. But the "nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/home/parth/nginx/var/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)" error still remains. Should I be worried about it?

Comment: the only problem is that I deploy this to another directory ... I will probably setup some kind of placeholder which can be replaced using sed.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`error_log`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) config directive.

Comment: I already tried. It doesn't work. I added "error_log  logs/error.log;" to nginx.conf file.